# Валидность :root

Tags: css, css3, валидация

Интересную особенность заметил.

`:root {}` на сайтах встречаю ооооочень редко, но при этом, натыкаюсь на статьи ([типо этой](https://frontender.info/css-variables-why-should-you-care/)), где говориться только о плюсах `:root` и других штуках.

Но при этом, при проверки валидации CSS на W3C получил аж 89 ошибок, связанных с `:root`.

Как быть? Как вы к этому относитесь?

Comment: Не с кажу с профессиональной точки зрения, но с практической,  сам сайт https://validator.w3.org/ мне указал на ошибки, в 100% рабочих стилях...  Скорее это проблема самого валидатора. А `:root` штука хорошая...  я пользуюсь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628908/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-root-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, читал этот вопрос, присоединяюсь к автору - по факту там ничего нет, почти.

Comment: @Air, придерживаюсь того же мнения. Если напишите коммент ответом, то отмечу как "правильный", если ответов больше не будет.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, мой коммент на ответ не смахивает...)))

Comment: К чему относимся? Если вы про использование `:root`, то только вместе с `CSS` переменными, в других случаях не использую и не видел, что бы другие использовали. А ваши ошибки могут быть связаны с устаревшим валидатором. [Здесь](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) все нормально.

Comment: @E_K, именно этим и проверял. Ошибки с CSS переменными и использование дефисов в классах, вот [ссылка](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.tumblr.com%2Flrzik8h%2FBHDpl6ix0%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=ru) в общем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет ничего неправильного в том, чтобы использовать CSS-переменные, да и `:root` тоже, это однозначно валидный код. Ошибки выкидывает просто потому, что парсер валидатора все еще не доработали — вероятно, по причине того, что спецификация custom properties все еще носит статус Candidate Recomendation.

Источники:
[псевдокласс `:root`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-root-pseudo), [CSS-переменные](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/).