# Как изменить значение пользовательского свойства :root через js/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Мне нужно по нажатию на кнопку менять `--litght-bg` на `--dark-bg` и наоборот у `bg-color`. Как это можно реализовать?

```css
:root{
  --litght-bg: #fff;
  --dark-bg: #000;
  --bg-color: var(--litght-bg);
}

body{
  background: var(--bg-color);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="btn">Пометять цвет</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Вы понимаете для чего нужен `:root`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628908/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-root-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC/635161

Answer (score 1):

мне нужно было изменить root:, и вот нашёл как это сделать.

```
//js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-color', '4px solid green');
//css
:root 
{
    --primary-color: 1px solid red;    
}

//html
<input class="testElem" type="button"value="on/off" onclick="test()">
```

вот ссылка на решении вашей задачи. https://frontender.info/css-variables-why-should-you-care/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
  $(':root').css('--bg', '#f00');
});
```

```css
:root {
  --bg: #000;
}

.bg {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: var(--bg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bg"></div>

<input type="button" value="change bg">
```